# Android.mk debug output

Tags: python, android, debugging, build, trace

I am building Froyo, is it possible that during building, make/python can output the file and the command it is calling right now.

For example, in one of the Android.mk, there is a line, says,
echo build success.
On the monitor it will show "build success", 
what I want is that in addition, it shows 
"Android.mk line 20: echo build success".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The message parser of the android make comment accepts info and warning tags in your Android.mk.

For example, If you want to print the value of an internal variable:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_ERRNO_H -g
$(info value of LOCAL_CFLAGS is: $(LOCAL_CFLAGS))
```

the info tells the compiler to print info debug output.

You can do the same with warning and error

```
$(warning value of LOCAL_CFLAGS is: $(LOCAL_CFLAGS))
```

would print a highlighted warning message

and

```
$(error value of LOCAL_CFLAGS is: $(LOCAL_CFLAGS))
```

would print the message and stop the build.

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced an odd effect of using $(info) when compiling a java+C++ Android application:

I used $info) to output some informations about conditional compiling in the Android.mk of the main application and when trying to debug the native part of the program, using ndk-gdb, it failed because apparently the output of $(info) is read by the ndk-gdb script (using the get_build_var() and get_build_var_for_abi() functions).
THe result is that the ndk-gdb script is not executed properly.